# Apache Flink - write Parquet file to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, parquet, flink-streaming

I have a Flink streaming pipeline that reads the messages from Kafka, the message has s3 path to the log file. Using the Flink async IO I download the log file, parse & extract some key information from them. I now need to write this extracted data (Hashmap<String, String>) as Parquet file back to another bucket in S3. How do I do it?
I have completed till the transformation, I have used 1.15 flink version. The Parquet format writing is unclear or some methods seem to be deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [FileSink](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/datastream/filesystem/#file-sink). There are some examples in the documentation, but here's an example that writes protobuf data in Parquet format:

```java
final FileSink<ProtoRecord> sink = FileSink
    .forBulkFormat(outputBasePath, ParquetProtoWriters.forType(ProtoRecord.class))
    .withRollingPolicy(
        OnCheckpointRollingPolicy.builder()
            .build())
    .build();

stream.sinkTo(sink);
```

Flink includes support for Protobuf and Avro. Otherwise you'll need to implement a `ParquetWriterFactory` with a custom implementation of the `ParquetBuilder` interface.

The `OnCheckpointRollingPolicy` is the default for bulk formats like Parquet. There's no need to specify that unless you go further and include some custom configuration -- but I added it to the example to illustrate how the pieces fit together.

Comment: but the incoming data is not proto but a hashmap that has values

Comment: I still am unclear here - should I have to have a class that implements the protobuf `Message`, so the hashmap is transformed to probuf message to write to parquet?

Comment: There's no requirement to use protobuf; that's just an example. I've expanded my answer with more details.

Comment: I have issue trying this David, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72210918/apache-flink-writing-stream-to-s3-error-null-uri-host