# Apache Flink - writing stream to S3 error - null uri host

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink data pipeline that transforms the log file downloaded from S3 and write back in parquet file format to another S3 bucket. I have configured the S3 key & secret in `flink-conf.yaml` with the

```
s3.access-key: "key"
s3.secret-key: "secret"
```

Additionally copied the `flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.15.0.jar` & `aws-java-sdk-1.12.217.jar` to `FLINK_HOME/plugins/s3-fs-presto` directory.

When the job is submitted to the cluster using `flink run`  command, I get the below exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null uri host.
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.create(AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.java:166)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.PluginFileSystemFactory.create(PluginFileSystemFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.getUnguardedFileSystem(FileSystem.java:508)
    at org.apache.flink.core.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:409)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink$BulkFormatBuilder.createBucketWriter(FileSink.java:669)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink$BulkFormatBuilder.getCommittableSerializer(FileSink.java:660)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink.getCommittableSerializer(FileSink.java:175)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null uri host.
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.S3xLoginHelper.buildFSURI(S3xLoginHelper.java:73)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.setUri(S3AFileSystem.java:486)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:246)
    at org.apache.flink.fs.s3.common.AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.create(AbstractS3FileSystemFactory.java:127)
    ... 41 more
```

The code to write the data to s3 is below

```
public static FileSink<Recc> getFileSink() {
        Item<Recc> item = new Item<>(Recc.class);
        ParquetWriterFactory<Recc> factory = AvroParquetWriters.forReflectRecord(item.getT());
        Path path = new Path("s3a:", "log-backup/", "vvra/logs"); //s3 also tried
        return FileSink.forBulkFormat(
                path,
                factory)
                .build();
    }
```

I even tried the minio but still I get the same error. How do resolve this? What more has to be configured?

Comment: Did you try to remove the colon ":" in the scheme name? I see you have "s3a:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was `:` (colon). It was not clearly documented

Answer (score 0):

You just need to remove the colon ":" in the scheme name. As the JavaDocs of `java.net.URI` state:

> ... If a scheme is given then it is appended to the result, followed
> by a colon character (':'). ...

`org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path` relies on `java.net.URI` under the hood.